# Tracking user and Remote access in windows form application C# Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have two questions in Windows Application.

1. I My application is using by two people and i want to track which user has saved this data and which user has edit it.I need to logged in user activity.

Do I need to pass login id to all forms and save there?Is there any other way?

1. I Installed my Application and Sqlserver database on one computer/machine. How the other user will use the same application from his computer in same office.

Comment: Have you trying some code?

Comment: Yes i am passing variable to second form like form2.Show(IsAdmin); where IsAdmin set to true in login form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your questions

1/**Do I need to pass login id to all forms and save there?Is there any other way?**

You must implement the features of user registration and authentification , in login phase the program will check the existence of the user ( login, password) in your database (I assume your database is ready) . If the user exists, you will have many choices

1. Put the user object as a static object
2. serialize the user object

So you can check the identity of the user during the execution of the program

2/ **I Installed my Application and Sqlserver database on one computer/machine. How the other user will use the same application from his computer in same office.**

You must put your machine as a server machine and allow the office members to access to it and to your application by remote connection

Perhaps it helps you :)

Comment: First Point is Clear now,Can you please explaine second point??

Comment: you allow your office's members to access to your machine , an idea Create connection to Remote Desktop Session Host using the windows command `Mstsc`  take a look here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753907(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Can we do in a way to put db on one machine and from all devices we create connection string to that machine.Can we access remote database ans is this a better approach?

Comment: Yes you can do this : put your database in machine X , your application in another machine Y but you must allow user to connect to it and you must change your connection string by adding the ip of the X machine. Is it a best approach? I think it depends from your needs ( security issue, queries are optimized or not ( because in remote connection it takes more time to be executing), working in a team (db manager, developper, designers...) makes the machine separation good approach , etc...)

Comment: I agreed with this way..I have database in machine X and i want to use it from X & Y & Z machines(by installing my app)...Can you give me some detail link? Thanks in advance

Comment: @user3244721 You are welcome . I assume you use Sql Server , to enable the remote connection check this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx . For the modification of the connection string take a look here https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/